# Apache Airflow - How to run multiple python files with different venv’s

Tags: python, python-venv, airflow

I’m very new to Apache Airflow. I have some python projects I’d like to be automated on Airflow and the way I have them set up is as follows:

```
*Python Project 1 -> venv_1
.
.
.
*Python Project N -> venv_N
```

**Is there a way when executing python programs to change the virtual environments (either dag-level or perhaps even task level)?**

**I’ve seen something on https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html for `classairflow.operators.python_operator.PythonVirtualenvOperator` but am just wondering if im on the right track or not.**

*I did things this way so that I could keep a ‘clean’ global python library with only stock functionality and only have the requirements I need on a per-project basis.

Many thanks to those smarter than I am! :)